# Format output c++ with setw

Tags: c++

I want to output a timetable but I'm having trouble getting it visually organized.

On the first line I want to print 3 strings.
On the second I want to print the related hours.

```
int main()
{
    string day1 = "Monday";
    string day2 = "Tuesday";
    string day3 = "Wednesday";

    cout << setw(10) << day1 << setw(10) << day2 << setw(10) << day3 << endl;

    int hour1 = 8;
    int hour2 = 9;
    int hour3 = 10;

    int min1 = 05;
    int min2 = 20;
    int min3 = 30;

    cout << setw(10) << hour1 << ":" << min1 << setw(10) << hour2 << ":" << min2 << setw(10) << hour3 << ":" << min3 << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This doesn't come out visually satisfying.
There's also the trouble with "05" min.

It goes something like in the following picture.

How can I get it right?

Thank you

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FUxm.png)

Comment: Post your desired output as _text_. And frankly this just seems like a "do it for me" post? What's "the trouble"? Can you narrow it down to a specific question please?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition definitely not a do it for me. I just created this example so people wouldnt have to be wasting time going through a more complex code I have right now. The problem is I have 2 variables and I want to put them together. If it was just a string it would be easy using setw, as everything would be aligned. But how does it work when you have more than 1 variable followed by each other? 
And how do I do it to print 05 instead of 5?

Comment: @N.Car: regarding printing "05", you pad it with zeros, before setting the width- like this:  setfill('0') << setw(2) << min1 . This should print "05" for the min1 variable. if width is set to something more than 2, then all empty spaces before the actual value will be padded with 0's.

Comment: never write a constant with `0` prefix unless you really know what it's doing

Comment: Also, as stated above, integers shouldn't be stored wit a 0 prefix. Instead, just store the min1 value as 5, and the format your output to using padding- as stated above. Only hexadecimal numbers and Octal numbers use prefixes such as 0x5(hexadecimal) 05(octal). Decimal base numbers do not have 0 prefixes in c++.

Comment: @BuddhaLight it doesn't seem to be working setfill('0') << setw(2). It will fill with 0's all the next empty spaces, even for other variables

Comment: @BuddhaLight: Integers aren't "stored" with _any_ prefix.

Comment: @Boundary, yes, I know -  read above please.

Comment: @N.Car :  you  will need to repeat the same process (of setting padding and width) , for each successive variable- some thing like this: cout << setw(8) << hour1 << ":" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << min1 << setfill(' ') << setw(10) << hour2 << ":" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << min2 << setfill(' ') <<setw(10) << hour3 << ":" << min3 << endl;

Comment: @BuddhaLight perfect!! I didn't know I had to setfill(' ') after so it doesnt affect the remaining spaces. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: :) You're welcome. happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second `setw(10)` only works for the thing that comes after it, which in this case is `hour1`. If you want to make it look good you can adjust your `setw()`.
Something like: `cout << setw(7) << hour1 << ":" << setw(2) << min1`

Comment: Thank you, I now understand it!!
One last thing, do you know how to add the 05? When I want to print 05, it only shows 5

Comment: You can use 'setfill('0')' in front of your number. Something like 'setfill('0') << min1'. Acceptance is appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you, Although I have to use setfill(' ') after so it doesnt influence the remaining spaces. :)

Comment: @N.Car, that is because `setfill()` is a sticky setting.